# How to change the OutputFormat of the Power operator in FortranForm

Tags: output-formatting, format

I'm trying to have Mathematica automatically give me an equation which I can use in a different programming language.  FortranForm produces output which is very similar to what the other language is expecting, except for the Power[] operator.

Basically, my problem is this - I would like to see the following output from Mathematica:

```
In= FortranForm[a^b]
Out= a^b
```

Rather than what it currently does, which is:

```
In= FortranForm[a^b]
Out= a**b
```

I think I can redefine the formatting of Power to do what I want with:

```
Unprotect[Power]
Format[Power[args__], FortranForm]:= <something here i can't figure out>
```

Does anyone know how to modify the formatting of Power when using FortranForm?

Answer (score 2):

Don't monkey with adding definitions to `Power`. Try something like

```
StringReplace[ToString[1+ 3 c+ a^b, FortranForm], "**" -> "^"]
```

> ```
> "1 + a^b + 3*c"
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish what you want by making use of [`SequenceForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceForm) (to put elements in sequence) and [`OutputForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OutputForm) (to hide quotation marks):

```
Unprotect[Power];
powerPrec = Precedence[Power];

Format[Power[x_,y_],FortranForm]:=With[
    {
    xx=If[Precedence[Head[x]]<powerPrec, pform[x], x],
    yy=If[Precedence[Head[y]]<powerPrec, pform[y], y]
    },

    SequenceForm[xx, Format["^",OutputForm],yy]
]
Protect[Power];

Format[pform[x_], FortranForm] := SequenceForm[Format["(", OutputForm], x, Format[")", OutputForm]]
```

Some examples:

```
a^b //FortranForm
```

> a^b

```
(1+x)^2 //FortranForm
```

> (1 + x)^2

```
(a+1/4)^(2 d) //FortranForm
```

> (0.25 + a)^(2*d)